# Why is my topFrame not the colour I chose but the bottomFrame is?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am using Tkinter, with pyhton 2.7, to create a Tkinter window that has a topFrame and bottomFrame. The topFrame have multiple pages I can select. When I created the containers I made the topFrame green and the bottomFrame Blue. however when I run the code the topFrame is grey.

dashboard.py:

```
from Tkinter import *
from page1 import PageOne
from page2 import PageTwo
from page3 import PageThree

class FullscreenWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.configure(background='black')

        #Create Containers
        self.buttonFrame = Frame(self.tk, background='black')
        self.topFrame = Frame(self.tk, bg="green")
        self.bottomFrame = Frame(self.tk, bg="blue")

        #Resize containers
        self.buttonFrame.pack(side="top", fill="x", expand=False)
        self.topFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.bottomFrame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        #Define Pages
        self.pageOne = PageOne(self.tk)
        self.pageTwo = PageTwo(self.tk)
        self.pageThree = PageThree(self.tk)

        #Place Pages in Containers
        self.pageOne.place(in_=self.topFrame, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.pageTwo.place(in_=self.topFrame, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
        self.pageThree.place(in_=self.topFrame, x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

        #Create Navigation Buttons
        self.buttonOne = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Page 1", command=self.pageOne.lift)
        self.buttonTwo = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Page 2", command=self.pageTwo.lift)
        self.buttonThree = Button(self.buttonFrame, text="Page 3", command=self.pageThree.lift)

        #Format Buttons
        self.buttonOne.pack(side="left")
        self.buttonTwo.pack(side="left")
        self.buttonThree.pack(side="left")

        #Display Page 1 by default
        self.pageOne.show()

        #Bind Enter Key to Toggle FullScreen
        self.state = False
        self.tk.bind('<Return>', self.toggle_fullscreen)

    def toggle_fullscreen(self, event=None):
        self.state = not self.state

        self.tk.attributes('-fullscreen', self.state)
        return 'break'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = FullscreenWindow()
    w.tk.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    w.tk.geometry('720x1280')
    w.tk.mainloop()
```

page1.py:

```
import Tkinter as tk
from page import Page

class PageOne(Page):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      Page.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

page.py:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def show(self):
        self.lift()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top frame is the color you specify. It's simply that it is completely hidden by the page instances.

You can see this by changing how you place the pages in the frame:

```
self.pageOne.place(in_=self.topFrame, relx=.05, rely=.05, relwidth=.9, relheight=.9)
self.pageTwo.place(in_=self.topFrame, relx=.05, rely=.05, relwidth=.9, relheight=.9)
self.pageThree.place(in_=self.topFrame, relx=.05, rely=.05, relwidth=.9, relheight=.9)
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont see any options in the place() documentation that suggests you can change the colour of this in those lines. Is there a workaround, some way to make it so that the background is tranparent

Comment: Nevermind. I found the line I needed to edit. Thank you.

Comment: No, you cannot make the background of a frame transparent.